# if statement doesn't work for counter variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my script to execute a method, when the scrollCount variable reaches a value > 2.

Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var scrolly = 0;
  var scrollCount = 0;
  console.log(scrollCount);


  $('#wizard-next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrolly -= 300;
    $( "#wizard-step-1" ).animate({ marginTop: (scrolly+'px') }, 1200);
    scrollCount++;
    console.log(scrollCount);
  });

  $('#wizard-prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrolly += 300;
    $( "#wizard-step-1" ).animate({ marginTop: (scrolly+'px') }, 1200);
    scrollCount--;
    console.log(scrollCount);
  });

  if(scrollCount > 2) {
    console.log('Add method here!');
  }


});
```

The if statement doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Comment: it works ... `scrollCount ` will only ever be 0 when that if statement is run, which is **once**, on document.ready

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Your `if` statement is outside an event handler, meaning it will only execute once at pageload.

Comment: @adeneo: correct. I added the if statement to the click event and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(scrollCount > 2) {
    console.log('Add method here!');
 }
```

As I'm sure you've noticed from the comments (@Jaromanda), the if statement is only done once. Which of course at that moment is false, since scollCount will be 0.

If you want it to be called everytime a click occurs then suround it by a function.

```
var scrollCountCheck = function(){
  if(scrollCount > 2) {
    console.log('Add method here!');
  }
}
```

And call this method in each of your click functions. right after or before scrollCount++ or scrollCount-- (depending on when you actually intended on calling it)